# Tor Browser 8.0.6 always turns on webgl.min_capability_mode

Tags: browser, tor, firefox

I want to enable webgl in the Tor Browser 8.0.6. In about:config, all settings are saved except `webgl.min_capability_mode`, which is always set to `true`. Whatever I do, this value is always set `true`. All other webgl.*-changes are persistent. I tried adding a new default profile with a custom `user.js` file, without any success.

How can I achieve `webgl.min_capability_mode` set to `false` on startup in the Tor Browser 8.0.6? Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option being "true" is somewhat a feature of TOR Browser. According to
[Mozilla Developer Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API),

> WebGL (Web Graphics Library) is a JavaScript API for rendering interactive 3D
>   and 2D graphics within any compatible web browser without the use of plug-ins.
>
> ```
> webgl.min_capability_mode
> ```
>
> A Boolean property that, when true, enables a minimum capability mode.
>   When in this mode, WebGL is configured to only support the bare minimum
>   feature set and capabilities required by the WebGL specification.

TOR Browser wants to minimize users' *digital fingerprint* by disabling
JavaScript for every websites. As in the quoted docs, WebGL is a JavaScrpit API.
So, `webgl.min_capability_mode: "true"` is default value. To make it false,
here TOR can be [customized with autoconfig](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig).

Assume the TOR is installed in `C:\Tor` folder. Create `autoconfig.js` file in
`C:\Tor\defaults\pref\autoconfig.js` path with these lines:

```
// This line is a comment
pref("general.config.filename", "firefox.cfg");
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
```

Create `firefox.cfg` file in `C:\Tor\mozilla.cfg` path. Add these following lines:

```
// This line is comment
lockPref("webgl.min_capability_mode", false);
```

The file name should match with the previous preference in `autoconfig.js`.
Here `lockPref` locks the preference to false. In my opinion, I am not suggesting
to change the default value. TOR does this to anonymize user identity.

#### Further Readings:

- [WebGL: 2D and 3D graphics for the web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API)
- [Customizing Firefox Using AutoConfig](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig)
- [WebGL best practices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/WebGL_best_practices)
- [TOR ticket: webgl.min_capability_mode might be too minimal](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/16005)

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. I was puzzled because I could change some values and some not. Unfortunately, min_capability_mode is indeed very minimal, it breaks some pages.